# Почему не роутится адрес с обратным адресом?

Tags: yii2

вот собственно адрес

```
http://film.lc/films/
```

вот правило

```
'films/'=>'/film/category/all',
```

но получаю 404 ошибку. а вот так все в порядке

```
http://film.lc/films
```

открывается мне надо что бы открывалось по этому адресу

```
http://film.lc/films/.
```

а тут `http://film.lc/films` я редирект настрою

Где туплю не подскажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартный UrlRule будет по-умолчанию триммить слэши в начале и в конце (причем как в шаблоне, так и в роуте), поэтому что

```
'films/'=>'/film/category/all'
```

что

```
'///films'=>'film/category/all///'
```

будут работать одинаково, как

```
'films' => 'film/category'
```

Чтобы это "обойти", вы можете закончить ваш паттерн регулярным выражением.

Например, если вы хотитите чтобы правило срабатывало только на `/films` либо `/films/`:

```
'films<slashOrNothing:\/?.{0,0}>' => 'film/category'
```

Или если нужно поймать что-то конкретное после слеша и переслать в контроллер:

```
'films<nothingOrSomethingWithSlash:.{0,0}|\/.*>' => 'film/category'
```

Ну и соответствующий параметр можно будет ловить в контроллере:

```
\Yii::$app->request->get('nothingOrSomethingWithSlash')
```